# Accuracy loss in single-precision Euclidean norm computation

Tags: fortran, error-estimation, floating-point, precision

I do hydrodynamics simulations with Fortran and recently I met with this issue:
I have a single-precision array `b` of length `n=512**3`, and I wish to compute the root-mean-squre of its elements. All I do is

```
s=0
do i=1,n
  s=s+b(i)**2
enddo
```

and then compute `sqrt(s/n)`.

I found that it makes about $30\%$ difference in the result depending on whether I have declared `s` as single-precision (`real`) or double-precision (`real*8`). My question is which should be the correct way to do?

My naive understanding is that, when I use `real*8 s`, the code will first convert `b(i)` into double precision and then do the computation. In that case, single-precision values in `b` will be padded with zeros in base 2, which makes them slightly change in base 10. Even so, I thought it was still accurate in base 2 and there should be no harm of promoting them to double precision before the computation. On the other hand, if I stick to single precision then each time I take the square `b(i)**2`, there is some tiny error introduced. Based on these arguments I though `real*8` should be the right choice.

If my thoughts above were correct, does it mean one need to go for quadruple precision when dealing with double-precision data?

I'm pretty new to numerical computations and Fortran, so any answers/comments will be helpful!

Comment: @njuffaGiven that the result may differ by 30 percent, perhaps I do need to distinguish between them.

Comment: Firstly real*8 is never the right choice as it is not, and has never been, part of standard Fortran - learn about Fortran kind values which is the correct way to use multiple precisions in Fortran, see e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/838310/fortran-90-kind-parameter Then as @njuffa says what you choose depends upon the accuracy you require. You might also look at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kahan_summation_algorithm which might give you the accuracy you require without having to go to quad precision.

Comment: @IanBush Your comment is very helpful, thanks! Using this algorithm I got same answers for real/real*8 s. I will also have a look at the meaning of real*8!

Comment: @IanBush Please do not answer in comments.

Comment: @OP "which makes them slightly change in base 10" is incorrect. Conversion from `binary32` to `binary64` is exact. An error of this kind may have been introduced earlier, in conversions from strings or literal constants typed inside your source code.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The squares are harmless (as long as they don't overflow/underflow), because the relative perturbation they introduce is of the order of the machine precision $u\approx 10^{-8}$. Your troubles here come from the $n\approx 10^8$ sums you are performing in sequence, which introduce an error of the order of $nu\approx 1$. You can confirm this by replacing each machine-sum $a\oplus b$ with $(a+b)(1+\delta_i)$ and bounding the error with $|\delta_i|\leq u$, or by checking the error analysis of scalar products and summation in Chapters 3 and 4 of Higham's *accuracy and stability of numerical algorithms*.

In any case, your possibilities are three:

- conversion to higher precision, as you have already tried.
- compensated summation (Kahan's algorithm), which has been suggested in the comments.
- pairwise summation, in which you sum numbers two by two recursively according by a binary tree. This reduces the $nu$ factor to $u\log_2 n$. It is the only strategy that does not require to increase the total number of floating-point operations, but the book-keeping involved may be more expensive than switching to the other methods.

This is explained also in Chapter 4 of [Higham's book](https://nhigham.com/accuracy-and-stability-of-numerical-algorithms/), which I suggest you to read in detail if you are interested in the details.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your nice answer!